# If the probability of frame being lost is $P.$ Then, calculate the mean no. of transmission for the frame to make it success$.$

Tags: probability, probability-theory, discrete-mathematics, permutations, expected-value

Here the probability of frame being lost is $P.$ So the probability of frame reaching safely would be $(1-P).$

Now lets consider that the frame will reach safely in $k$-th transmission. That means that the frame being lost $k-1$ times and reached in $k$-th time with probability $(1-P).$ Now a frame requires $k$-transmissions exactly when the first $k-1$ attempts fail .... this happens with probability $P^{ \text{k-1} }$  and the $k$-th transmission succeeds , this happens with probability $1-P.$

For $k=1,$ the probability $= (1-P)$

For $k=2,$ the probability $= P(1-P)$

For $k=3,$ the probability $=$ $P^2$$(1-P)$
$.............. 
.............  {\infty}$

So the mean number of transmission will be $= (1-P) + P(1-P) +$ $P^2$$(1-P)$$.......... $Which gives me $1.$
But here mean of the transmission will have to be calculated not the probability mean.So how to calculate the mean of the transmission?
But solution saying,

$\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} kP_k$

$=$ $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} k(1-P)P^{k-1}$

$=$$(1-P)$$\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}kP^{k-1}$

$= (1-P).$$\frac1{{(1-P)}^2}$ $=$$\frac1{{(1-P)}}$

I don't understand how they multiply $P^{ \text{k-1} }$$(P-1)$ by $k.$

Comment: Here you have already computed the probability mass function (pmf) $p(k)$ of the geometric random variable. So when you summing the pmf, $\sum_{k=1}^{+\infty} p(k) = 1$. And this is not the mean. To calculate the mean, you sum $\sum_{k=1}^{+\infty} kp(k)$. This is the definition of the mean of a discrete random variable.

Comment: @Bgm, during sum why k is multiplied?

Comment: @BGM how to prove mean of a discrete random variable?

Comment: That is the definition: See e.g. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expected_value#Countably_infinite_case
Intuitively $k$ are the outcomes of the random variable, the "location", while the pmf is the weight. So it is a "weighted average" of all possible outcomes.

Comment: @Bgm, could you iterate with one example in answer... From that I can generalize the formula.. From wiki it is difficult to understand... Please give the with simple example..

Comment: For example, for a uniform dice, with the probability of each face being $1/6$, the expected value is $1 \times 1/6 + 2 \times 1/6 + 3 \times 1/6 + 4  \times 1/6 + 5 \times 1/6 + 6 \times 1/6 = 21/6 = 7/2$. In this example you see $k$ range from $1$ to $6$ and $p(k) = 1/6$

Comment: @Bgm but how can you find average for k=1.....to infinity, this is the question..

Comment: Yes not every distribution has an expectation. For unbounded distribution like this, you require the pmf goes to zero fast enough (thin tail) such that the summation converge. Sum to infinity (infinite series) require you to evaluate the limit of a sequence of partial sums.

Comment: Cross-posted: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4256012/14578, https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/144033/755, https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/q/76312/29837.  Please [do not post the same question on multiple sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/64068).

Answer (score 2):

$$EX = \sum_{x \in X} x * p(x)$$ here

$$p(X=x) = P^{x-1}(1-P)$$
$$EX = \sum_{x = 1}^{\infty} xp(X=x) = \sum_{x = 1}^{\infty} xP^{x-1}(1-P)=\frac{1}{1-P}$$

you initially calculated this:
$$\sum_{x \in X} p(x)=1$$

Comment: could you explain why  $x$ is multiplying by $p(x)$, it is my question.

Comment: @Saslok, the expected value of a random variable $X$, is precisely $\sum_x x p(x)$. It is the weighted average of all possible values of the variable $X$.

Comment: @Malkoun ${\sum xp(x)}$, could you proof this with example.

Comment: @Saslok, it is the definition of the expected value of a random variable. For example, suppose $X$ can only take on the values: 1, with probability 1/4, 2, with probability 1/2 and 3 with probability 1/4, then the expected value of X is $1*1/4 + 2*1/2 + 3*1/4 = 2$.

Comment: @ Malkoun I understand all things. But if you proof ${\sum xp(x)}$ with example everything will be fine for me. I understand with  dice example with 6 faces. But how to calculate average of infinite faces ?

Comment: @Saslok   it's like with infinite signal response, think about sound that fades in resonance chamber - technically you will still have it's energy after long time but it fades, now think that you add up energy of all sounds that was playing in one second interspace one after another but are fading with every second, and this fading is $p$ which is getting smaller but it still contributes to overall energy sum, that's why infinite series have applications in physics